# Delete items in a BOM within a certain range

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

I want to delete the items used to build wire harnesses within a BOM (BOM of each item)
Could you help me with a code snippet on how to delete items within a certain range?

[image: BOM]

The range is undefined and each level has a unique range.

I'm expecting the code to "delete" all level 3 items and just return a data frame with level 2 items
[image: expected result]

Comment: "BOM" could mean either "byte order mark" or "bill of materials". Obviously you mean the latter, but you might expand the abbreviation in your question.

Answer (score 0):

This function takes as arguments your DataFrame (table), column name and array of values you want to delete from table:

```
def deleter(df, column, values):
    for value in values: 
        df.drop(df[df[column] == value].index, 
            inplace=True)
    return df
```

In your particular example you need to call this function this way (df is variable with your table):`deleter(df, “Level”, [3])`